# How To Retrieve The Meta Tag Property For open Graph using HP UFT or Selenium Webriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, qtp, hp-uft

I am trying to verify the open graph meta tag  &  in our site. Here is the HTML code:

```
<div class="atg_store_applicationResourceContainer">
            </div>
      <meta name="robots" content="index, follow" />

            <!--  Coming inside regular metadetails-->
                            <!-- contentKey =  -->

        <!--  SEOTagID -  **** -->
    <title>Sectional Living Rooms&nbsp;</title>
                <meta name="description" content="Find Sectional Living Rooms&amp;nbsp; that will look great in your home and complement the rest of your furniture." />
                <meta name="author" content="EXAMPLE.com" />

        <meta name="google-site-verification" content="UscxdOsY5bXX9hk_Y0GILMPvzsL66vDcHHwkZZ7Gxpg" />

        <meta property="og:title" content="Sectional Living Rooms&nbsp;"/>
        <meta property="og:site_name" content="EXAMPLE"/>
            <!-- requestSocialUrl = http://www.example.com/cartridges/PageSlot/PageSlot.jsp -->
      <!-- customCanonical = http://www.example.com/furniture/Living-Rooms/Sectional-Living-Rooms/_/N-8wh -->
                       <link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com/furniture/Living-Rooms/Sectional-Living-Rooms/_/N-8wh" /> <!-- add + instead of space in words for SEO -->
                              <meta property="og:image" content="http:/images/unavailable.gif?$PDP_Cart_Primary_150x150$" />
            <meta property="og:type" content="product"/>
        <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.example.com/furniture/Living-Rooms/Sectional-Living-Rooms/_/N-8wh"/>
        <meta property="og:description" content="Find Sectional Living Rooms&amp;nbsp; that will look great in your home and complement the rest of your furniture.&amp;nbsp;#iSofa #abc"/>
    <script>var _adblock=true;</script>
```

I am trying to get the value of the `content` attribute from `meta` tags having the `property` attribute value as `og:title` & `og:description`. Any help would be helpful.

I am able to find get the content of the meta with names but am not able to get the content of `<og:title>` & `<og:description>` as the tag does not have a name

We are using both UFT &  Selenium Webdriver (Java). So I can use help on any single one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Selenium you can go with xpath like

```
//meta[@property='og:title']
//meta[@property='og:description']
```

And to get the content use `getAttribute()` method of the `WebElement`

```
 WebElement titleEl=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//meta[@property='og:title']"));
 String titleContent = titleEl.getAttribute("content");
```